# Can a rod be attached perpendicular to the motor shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering

So, I was trying to make something like this

[image].

However, While I have the motor, the motor has a vertical shaft and I need something to connect a rod to it in a T shape

Is this even possible? And if yes, then what should I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could design a "top hat" that sits on the motor shaft and is secured with a couple of grub screws at 90°, with a hole for the rod to go through (the rod can also be secured with a couple of grub screws or if the rod is threaded, use a threaded hole instead).

Here's an example with a 6mm diameter motor shaft and a 6mm diameter rod:

[image]

A detailed drawing of the part in question would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: It may be easier to manufacture if you drill the bottom hole to the other shafts hole.